# How to use data in a csv file with geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a csv file which has neumerical variables including longitude and latitude and also have few categorical variables. I want to use this csv with geopandas to plot map. but i am confused about shapefiles and how to use them. Can anyone tell me how do i start ?

Comment: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html

Comment: see especially https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html

Answer (score 0):

as per comments this is fully covered in documentation.  Another example

```
import pandas as pd
import io, requests
import geopandas as gpd

# read some CSV data
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(requests.get("https://assets.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),
    sep="Č",
    engine="python",
)

# long / lat columns to geodataframe geomtry all other columns attributes
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude, crs="EPSG:4326"), data=df
)

# exclude empty geometries and show it works
gdf.loc[~gdf.geometry.is_empty, :].explore(
    "Sector", cmap=["blue", "green"], height=300, width=300
)
```

#### output

[image]